# Differences between JFrame setVisible(false) and setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In Swing, we can hide `JFrame` by using two methods:

1. `frame.setVisible(false)`
2. `frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)`

The difference that I discover are:

1. `frame.setVisible(false)` removes icon from taskbar whereas `ICONIFIED` doesn't.
2. We can add listener to `ICONIFIED` whereas we can't add it for `frame.setVisible(false)`.

Is there other major difference I'm missing? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the default close operation of the frame?  That will change the behavior of `setVisible(false)`

Comment: JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE closes the frame and if its the only alive frame of program then program also closes. I know this much. Im confused by your comment "That will change the behavior of setVisible(false)".

Comment: Try using the others (`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` & `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`), consult the Java Docs for each while you're at it.  For `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556).  The icon(s) should appear in the task-bar until the last is closed.

Answer (score 2):

`With setVisible(false), if the Component is not already marked invisible, setVisible calls invalidate() which invalidates the Container’s layout and the chain of parents since there is now more screen real estate in the Container and the positions of the siblings must be adjusted to flow into the freed space.`

[API of Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

But the `ICONFIED` is doing the minimize process of a window.

Answer (score 1):

> We can add listener to ICONIFIED whereas we can't add it for frame.setVisible(false).

You can use a `ComponentListener` and handle `componentHidden(...)`.

Comment: ComponentListener is really new to me. can you give me some more difference and list them in points.

Answer (score 0):

The major differences as I know are as follows:
1) frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED) just changes the state of the frame whereas frame.setVisible(false)     changes visibility of frame.
2) setState(Frame.ICONIFIED) method in class java.awt.Frame can programmatically minimize a frame     and setState(Frame.NORMAL) to restore it.
3) Invisible frame cannot use any listener but you can add listener to frame that is ICONIFIED.
4) frame.setVisible(false) removes the physical state of frame from screen whereas     setState(Frame.ICONIFIED) just changes state preserving its physical state.

These two methods have their own characteristics so be more confident in choosing one that is more suitable for your situation.